# Splitting list in k subsets without altering order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list say `li=[1,4,2,5,2]`
and this list is to be splitted in `k=3` subsets 
I want output like this:

```
[
  [1,4,2],[5],[2]],
  [1,4],[2,5],[2],
  [1,4],[2],[5,2],
  [1],[4,2],[5,2],
  [1],[4],[2,5,2],
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combinations` of where splits should occur:

```
from itertools import combinations

out = [[
    li[i:j]
    for i,j in zip((0,) + ix, ix + (None,))
] for ix in combinations(range(1, len(li)), r=3-1)]
>>> out
[[[1], [4], [2, 5, 2]],
 [[1], [4, 2], [5, 2]],
 [[1], [4, 2, 5], [2]],
 [[1, 4], [2], [5, 2]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 5], [2]],
 [[1, 4, 2], [5], [2]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using recursion:

```
li = [1,4,2,5,2]
def subsets(d, k, c = []):
   if len(c) == k and len(li) == sum(map(len, c)):
      yield c
   elif d:
      if len(c) < k:
         yield from subsets(d[1:], k, c+[[d[0]]])
      if c:
         yield from subsets(d[1:], k, [*c[:-1], c[-1]+[d[0]]])

print(list(subsets(li, 3)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [4], [2, 5, 2]],
 [[1], [4, 2], [5, 2]], 
 [[1], [4, 2, 5], [2]], 
 [[1, 4], [2], [5, 2]], 
 [[1, 4], [2, 5], [2]], 
 [[1, 4, 2], [5], [2]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my very first answer on SO :)

I challenged myself to solve this issue using recursion (a topic I'm still actively trying to learn and understand) and without using *itertools*. Here is my solution.

Reading the other answers, I realise that I should use a generator to speed up calculation time and avoid hitting any limit.

```py
def validate_input_vlaues(li, k):
    """ check and validates input values """

    # k should be an integer higher than 0
    if not type(k) == int or k < 1:
        raise ValueError("k should be an integer higher than 0")
    # li should be a list of at least 1 element
    if not type(li) == list or len(li) < 1:
        raise ValueError("li should be a list of at least 1 element ")
    # li should be higher or equal to k
    if len(li) < k:
        raise ValueError("The lenght of li should be higher than or equal to k")

def split_list_in_subsets(li, k):
    """ Returns a list of all combinations when splitting a list {li} into {k} parts """

    # if k is 1 >> Recursion exit condition:
    # We cannot subdivide the list into more subsets
    if k==1:
        return [[li]]

    # if the length of li is higher or equal to k (and higher than 1)
    if len(li) >= k:

        # create an empty list to store the subset results to return
        output = list()

        # storing a prefix and the remaining list
        for i in range(0, len(li) - k + 1):
            prefix = li[:i+1]
            rest = li[i+1:]

            # recursively run the function on the remaining list, k being 1 subset smaller (prefix)
            subsets = split_list_in_subsets(rest, k-1)

            # add to the output list all subsets with current prefix
            for sub in subsets:
                output.append([prefix] + sub)

        return output


# main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Initial values (list, int)
    li = [1,4,2,5,2]
    k = 3

    ### Checking input values
    validate_input_vlaues(li, k)

    ### Calculating solutions ###
    solutions = split_list_in_subsets(li, k)

    ### printing the results ###
    print(f"Liste: {li}\nSubsets: {k}\n")
    print(f"{len(solutions)} Solution(s):\n")
    for sub in solutions:
        print(sub)
```

Output:

```py
Liste: [1, 4, 2, 5, 2]
Subsets: 3

6 Solution(s):

[[1], [4], [2, 5, 2]]
[[1], [4, 2], [5, 2]]
[[1], [4, 2, 5], [2]]
[[1, 4], [2], [5, 2]]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [2]]
[[1, 4, 2], [5], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

output = [(li[:start], li[start:end], li[end:]) for start, end in combinations(range(1, len(li)), 2)]

>>> output
[[[1], [4], [2, 5, 2]],
 [[1], [4, 2], [5, 2]],
 [[1], [4, 2, 5], [2]],
 [[1, 4], [2], [5, 2]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 5], [2]],
 [[1, 4, 2], [5], [2]]]
```